# Opencart Multimerch 7 seller order notification

Tags: opencart

I have a multivendor website based on Opencart 2.0.3.1 + MultiMerch 7. The problem is that sellers don't receive order notification mail (when someone buys their items), but only the admin. So I have to send notices to sellers manually.

Has anyone encountered this problem and maybe has a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Martin, the founder of MultiMerch here.

First, I'd strongly recommend you upgrade to MultiMerch 8 if possible as the latest stable version of MM7 was released more than a year ago and [we've made a lot of progress with MultiMerch 8 since then](https://multimerch.com/resources/changelog/).

Second, you'll need to make sure that your order status is set to Complete or whatever you have specified in your "Complete order statuses" setting in Admin > MultiMerch > Settings > Finances. MultiMerch only generates vendor transactions for the statuses mentioned here so if your order is e.g. Pending, no transactions and emails will be triggered.

If this is not the case, you'll need to look into your mailserver configuration as well as into your OpenCart error log. Missing MultiMerch emails can be caused by a number of issues from checkout modifications to incorrect mail settings.